# SaveInstanceState of RecyclerView

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, linearlayoutmanager

this is my data

```
List<ItemData> data = new ArrayList<>();

LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
MyAdapter mAdapter;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
```

and this is my recycler view in OnCreate method

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
llm.setStackFromEnd(true);
mAdapter = new MyAdapter(data, getApplication());
recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
```

how can i use onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState to save my data list so doesn't dissapear in rotation?

Comment: use loaders. https://medium.com/google-developers/making-loading-data-on-android-lifecycle-aware-897e12760832

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not prefered but i used in every activity in my manifest

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```